# Improving Performance of LSTM for time series prediction

Tags: keras, lstm, rnn, sequence-to-sequence

My data consists of two features and a set of time series data labeled as "bookings". I have 1056 data point in the times series, for which I have two features for each. The data size is 1056x3.

My aim is to: given previous 21 data points and two features, predict the coming 7 data points.

I have prepared my data accordingly to make it suitable for LSTM and then trained my network.

My code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
data= pd.read_excel("data.xlsx", 'Sheet3')

n_in=28
n_out=7


for obs in range(1,n_in):
    data["T_" + str(obs)] = data.bookings.shift(obs)
data.fillna(0.00,inplace=True)

X=data
Y=data.get(["bookings"])
for obs in range(1,n_out+1):
    Y["T+" + str(obs)] = data.bookings.shift(-obs)
Y.fillna(0.00,inplace=True)
Y=Y.drop(["bookings"], axis=1)

X=X.values
Y=Y.values


data = np.concatenate((X,Y),axis=1)

Train=data[:740,:] 
Test=data[740:,:]

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
Train = scaler.fit_transform(Train)
Test = scaler.transform(Test)

Xtrain,Xtest=Train[:,:n_in+2], Test[:,:n_in+2]
Ytrain, Ytest=Train[:,-n_out:] , Test[:,-n_out:]


Xtrain = np.array(Xtrain).reshape(Xtrain.shape[0], 1, n_in+2)
Ytrain = np.array(Ytrain).reshape(Ytrain.shape[0], 1, n_out)
Xtest = np.array(Xtest).reshape(Xtest.shape[0], 1, n_in+2)
Ytest = np.array(Ytest).reshape(Ytest.shape[0], 1, n_out)
```

Then I create the LSTM Network and train it:

```
from keras.layers import RepeatVector
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM,Bidirectional
model = Sequential()

model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(80, activation= 'relu', input_shape=(1, n_in+2))))
model.add(RepeatVector(1))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(80, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(n_out)))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

history = model.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain, epochs=25, validation_split=0.2, verbose=1, batch_size=2)
```

Verbose of the training:

```
Train on 592 samples, validate on 148 samples
Epoch 1/25
592/592 [==============================] - 24s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0327 - val_loss: 0.0146
Epoch 2/25
592/592 [==============================] - 4s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0115 - val_loss: 0.0119
Epoch 3/25
592/592 [==============================] - 4s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0094 - val_loss: 0.0115
Epoch 4/25
592/592 [==============================] - 4s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0084 - val_loss: 0.0108
Epoch 5/25
592/592 [==============================] - 4s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0077 - val_loss: 0.0101
Epoch 6/25
592/592 [==============================] - 4s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0073 - val_loss: 0.0104
Epoch 7/25
592/592 [==============================] - 4s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0070 - val_loss: 0.0119
Epoch 8/25
592/592 [==============================] - 4s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0070 - val_loss: 0.0097
Epoch 9/25
592/592 [==============================] - 4s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0067 - val_loss: 0.0099
Epoch 10/25
592/592 [==============================] - 4s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0066 - val_loss: 0.0097
Epoch 11/25
592/592 [==============================] - 4s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0067 - val_loss: 0.0097
Epoch 12/25
592/592 [==============================] - 4s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0064 - val_loss: 0.0095
Epoch 13/25
592/592 [==============================] - 4s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0063 - val_loss: 0.0100
Epoch 14/25
592/592 [==============================] - 4s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0062 - val_loss: 0.0095
Epoch 15/25
592/592 [==============================] - 4s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0060 - val_loss: 0.0092
Epoch 16/25
592/592 [==============================] - 4s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0059 - val_loss: 0.0098
Epoch 17/25
592/592 [==============================] - 4s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0059 - val_loss: 0.0098
Epoch 18/25
592/592 [==============================] - 4s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0058 - val_loss: 0.0093
Epoch 19/25
592/592 [==============================] - 4s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0060 - val_loss: 0.0091
Epoch 20/25
592/592 [==============================] - 4s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0058 - val_loss: 0.0095
Epoch 21/25
592/592 [==============================] - 4s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0056 - val_loss: 0.0091
Epoch 22/25
592/592 [==============================] - 4s 6ms/step - loss: 0.0056 - val_loss: 0.0093
Epoch 23/25
592/592 [==============================] - 4s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0056 - val_loss: 0.0091
Epoch 24/25
592/592 [==============================] - 4s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0057 - val_loss: 0.0091
Epoch 25/25
592/592 [==============================] - 4s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0055 - val_loss: 0.0095
```

The loss gets stuck there and doesn't reduce with increasing the number of epochs.

Then I use the trained network to predict and test the performance. I scale back and reshape as well:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

yhat = model.predict(Xtest, verbose=0)
yhat=np.array(yhat).reshape(yhat.shape[0],yhat.shape[2])
Ytest=np.array(Ytest).reshape(Ytest.shape[0],Ytest.shape[2])
Xtest = np.array(Xtest).reshape(Xtest.shape[0],Xtest.shape[2])

temp=np.concatenate((Xtest,yhat),axis=1)
yhat= scaler.inverse_transform(temp)
yhat=yhat[:,-n_out:]

temp=np.concatenate((Xtest,Ytest),axis=1)
Ytest= scaler.inverse_transform(temp)
Ytest=Ytest[:,-n_out:]

rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(Ytest, yhat))
print('Test RMSE: %.3f' % rmse)
```

Some examples of my output, where the actual is in blue and prediction is in orange.
[image]
[image]
[image]

My questions are:

1. Is there any flaw in the steps above?
2. Any idea how can I improve the performance of the network?